# Protocol extensions where Self is generic

Tags: ios, swift

I have a `BaseViewController` that is defined this way:

```
open class BaseViewController<ViewModel: ViewModelType, View: BaseView>: UIViewController { ... }
```

I'm trying to write an extension for a protocol that has a default behaviour for all my BaseViewControllers. Something like this:

```
protocol MyProtocol { 
    func doStuff()
}

extension MyProtocol where Self: BaseViewController<BaseViewModel, BaseView> { 
    func doStuff() { ... }
}
```

However. If I only tells that the generic types are the `BaseViewModel` and `BaseView` it doesn't works for my subclasses, even though those are the most lower level classes used here.

How can I write my protocol extension in a way it will works for all my `BaseViewController` classes?

Comment: BaseViewController is a class. It already has real inheritance. You don’t need a protocol to inject functionality into it using fake inheritance.

Comment: In this case, this is a behaviour that I want that only some controllers that I specify have it. Not all BaseViewControlllers in the app.

Comment: Well, you won't have any "all BaseViewControllers". You will have lots of view controllers that _inherit_ from just _one_ BaseViewController. So you give BaseViewController some default behavior, and if a subclass of BaseViewController doesn't want to inherit that, it overrides it.